# ¿Cómo crear un programa para imprimir los divisores de un número? que no se muestre en consola

Tags: javascript, html5

he visto varias respuestas a esta pregunta pero es hecho por consola, yo lo quiero transmitir por medio de una página Html5, no soy experta en js, es una tarea de un curso que estoy teniendo y nada lo soluciona, cómo sería el ciclo tanto para while y como con for.

Ojo, no es por consola.

ESTE ES UNO DE LOS EJEMPLOS QUE QUISIERA CAMBIAR PARA QUE LO PUEDA VER EN LA PÁGINA

```
class divisores {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
 
        System.out.println ("Introduzca un Numero: ");
        String nu = br.readLine ();
        int n = Integer.parseInt (nu);
 
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
            if (n % i == 0)
                System.out.println (i);
    } }
```

Y ESTO ES LO QUE ESTOY HACIENDO

```
function proceso(){
                
                //entrada
                
                var num = parseInt(frmSerie1.txtNum.value); //numero
                var divisor = 2; //divisor
                
                //proceso   
                
                while(divisor>=0){
                    if(num%divisor == 0){
                        num /= divisor;
                        var resultado = "\nEncontramos divisor"+ divisor;
                    }else{
                        divisor = divisor + 1;
                    }
                    
                }
    
                //salida
                frmSerie1.txtResul.value = RESULTADO;
                
            }
```

¿Cómo se haría para crear una cadena que almacene todos los datos y sume los resultados?

Ejemplos

Número: 12

Resultado: Se encontraron 6 números divisores. 12, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La funcion que escribiste.. en que lenguaje esta?

Comment: Hola. Debes enfocar el problema: ejemplo: 1. ¿Donde lees el número? 2. ¿Cuando y por qué camino das la orden de ejecutar para obtener los divisores. 3. ¿cuantos números debes probar (hasta la raíz cuadrada del número)? 4. Donde guardas los divisores que encuentras? 5. Donde y como muestras el resultado? Prueba a hacerlo y si tropiezas nos muestras lo que hayas intentado y con gusto te ayudamos.

Comment: Buenas michelle!, bienvenida a la grieta del invocador, enrealidad... ten en cuenta que Java y Javascript son lenguajes de programacion completamente distintos entre si, y que la HTML5 esta sobrando, pues enrealidad en la pregunta nisiquiera lo estas usando... ahora bien, es acaso tu duda respecto a como podrias mostrar toda esta informacion en la pagina y no en consola?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola puedes hacer algo como esto:

```js
$("#boton").on("click", function(){
  var num =  $("#numero").val()//numero
                var resultado = [];

                //proceso

                for (i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
                      if(num%i == 0) { resultado.push(i);}
                }     

                //salida
                $("#resultado").text(resultado)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="numero" />
    <button id="boton">click</button>
    <br/>
    <p id="resultado"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es buena respuesta, pero ¿por qué usar jQuery? Creo que no se justifica cargar una librería para operaciones tan simples.

Comment: Porque me gusta más poner $(id) que document.getElementById(id) pero pues cada quien no :) Saludos

Comment: Es lo que se llama "matar moscas a cañonazos"

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por sus respuestas, ¿porqué puse html5? lo que pasa es que es una tarea que se va a mostrar en una página web, en un formulario que ya está creado, puse html5 porque el script va a estar en el head del documento, y agarra las variables de un input

```
 <input type="text" name="txtNum" class="form-control"
placeholder="Número">
```

se genera con el siguiente boton

```
 <input type="button" value="Divisores" class="btn
 button-primary-outline-v2" onClick="proceso()">
```

el resultado se muestra en el siguiente texarea

```
 <textarea name="txtResul" rows="10" cols="1"
 class="form-control"></textarea>
```

la mayoría de códigos que vi hacían todo por consola y no sabía cómo convertirlo todo a lo que quería, pero ya tengo la respuesta, se las muestro

```
function proceso(){
                    //entrada
                    var n = parseInt(frmSerie1.txtNum.value); //numero          > var cad = "";             var contador = 0;            var sumaDiv = 0;   for(var i=1;i<=n;i++){           if(n % i == 0){             cad += i + ",";
            contador++;
            sumaDiv += 1;
            contador++;             }

        }

        //salida             frmSerie1.txtResul.value = "Divisores: "+cad+ > > "\nN° divisores: " +sumaDiv;
                }
```

Comment: cómo puedo editar la pregunta principal? no me sale la opción

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la funcion

```
document.write()
```

Para imprimir en el archivo de html, o:

```
write()
```